# Camera and Audio Permission denied in cordova inappbrowser

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

Can anyone tell me how do I request html5 audio and video permissions when I visit a web page using inappbrowser?

I can't activate the cam I get this error;

`NotAllowedError: Permissin denied`

how do i use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia on Inappbrowser? I use cordova and I can't open the camera, I tried to install the plugins too.

Code

````
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    'audio': true
   }).then(function(mediaStream) {
      alert('si avvia');
      

   }).catch(function(err) {
     alert(err);
 });

}else{

alert('non supporta camera');
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the CAMERA and AUDIO permissions. Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions to add the permissions at runtime.